# A column count greater than AND a column count less than in the same SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Is there in SQL a possibility to SELECT the number records in a certain table which are equal or greater than a certain given boundary in a specific field and in the same query also the values which are less than the given boundary?

Comment: Can you please be more clear, because right now it's too complex

Comment: So, all numbers? Regardless of the boundary x, `number >= x OR number < x` is just all numbers. I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be talking about a simple "AND" statement needed in your where clause:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM MyTable WHERE MyVal >= 10 AND MyVal < 20.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand...

Something like this?

```
SELECT YOUR_KEY,
       MAX(FIELD_1) AS FIELD_1,
       MAX(FIELD_2) AS FIELD_2
FROM (SELECT YOUR_KEY,
             CASE WHEN YOUR_FIELD BETWEEN 1 AND 49
                  THEN YOUR_FIELD
                  ELSE NULL END AS FIELD_1,
             CASE WHEN YOUR_FIELD BETWEEN 50 AND 100
                  THEN YOUR_FIELD
                  ELSE NULL END AS FIELD_2
      FROM YOUR_TABLE)
GROUP BY YOUR_KEY;
```

Or something else?!

Answer (score 0):

What I exactly mean is that  I want to create a SELECT statement which give me the number of supportcalls which has been solved within the SLA agreement and the number of calls that didn't meet the agreement over a certain period, grouped by months.